# How to check a variable only contains spaces?

Tags: batch-file

As stated in the title, does anyone know how to check whether a variable contains only spaces in batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
if "%variable: =%"=="" (
    rem variable contains only spaces
)
```

`%variable: =%` is a form of `%haystack:needle=replace%`, searching for space and replacing with nothing.  So if you replace all spaces with nothing in the variable and the result equals nothing, then the variable contains only spaces.

---

**Edit:** Aacini is right.  The above `if` statement will evaluate true if the variable contains only spaces, but false if the variable is not defined.  Probably ought to check explicitly whether the variable is defined first.  Here's one way:

```js
if not defined variable (
    rem variable is not defiend
) else if "%variable: =%"=="" (
    rem variable contains only spaces
)
```

Here's another:

```js
if defined variable if not "%variable: =%"=="" goto valid
rem variable is either undefined or contains only spaces

:valid
```

Comment: Not exactly... When a variable is not defined, its `%expansion:...%` is different: the part from first percent up to the colon is removed, and also the last percent sign. For example, `"%variable: =%"` is replaced by `" ="` (space-equal), and `"%variable:~0,3%"` is replaced by `"~0,3"`